# Determining source line nubmer in ASM from offset in Android crashlog

Tags: android, assembly, crash, line-numbers, symbolicatecrash

I have a crash in Crashlytics, that occurs in libc.memcpy:

```
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0005d158  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__memcpy_a53+40) (BuildId: 1980ba02db10292648c1fc24639ec9c1)
      ...
```

On cs.android.com I can find the corresponding memcpy.S (Android 10):

bionic/libc/arch-arm/cortex-a53/bionic/memcpy.S

But now I want to locate the exact place in ASM, where crash is occured. How can I determine line number from __memcpy_a53+40?

Comment: If you don't have debug info you need to reverse engineer the code. Note that the fault is unlikely to be in memcpy itself, probably it got passed wrong arguments so I would instead look at the caller.

Comment: Take `objdump -d` to the libc.so file. The offending instruction is at offset 64 (40 hex) from start of `__memcpy_a53`. Find the same instruction (+surroundings) in memcpy_base.S .